# Problems making a .gitignore in a "main" module affect a submodule properly

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a currently existing directory structure I need to adhere to, which is similar to this: [workspace/project/src/htdocs/templates]. In the project directory I have a Git repository with the entire project in it. I also have a 'front-ends' directory in the workspace directory which is not currently included in the existing repository.

I want to have the workspace/front-ends & workspace/project/src/htdocs/templates directories contained in their own repositories - basically a separation of front-ends and code. (There will be a separate group of people working on these files and would like to have their changes independent of the code on the site.)  My idea was to create second repository in the workspace directory, and in the .gitignore file, exclude the /project/src/htdocs path - all except the /templates directory. I have been unsuccessful with this. I tried the following consecutive lines in the .gitignore file:

project/src/htdocs

!project/src/htdocs/templates (and also tried project/src/htdocs/templates/!*)

Both of these resulted in the files still being ignored by the secondary repository in workspace. I have been reading about Submodules, but I am not sure this is the correct way to accomplish this workflow. Is it possible to have the outer repository contained in workspace ignore the specified path and still recognize a directory in that path?

Comment: Folders are normally specified with the trailing slash: `project/src/htdocs/` and `!project/src/htdocs/templates/`. would that help?

Comment: Von, thank for the tip. I will try that and see if it does the trick...

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't alleviate the issue. Changes and new files are still not picked up. Thank you though...

Comment: Ok. Were those files already versioned? Because a `.gitignore` only ignores non-versioned files. If they were, a `git rm --cached yourFolder/` might help.

Comment: Von, I actually just recreated the paths and am using brand new test files with brand new repositories to try to test and develop the best workflow for this. I am starting to think the best way will be to just have 2 separate repositories, one in each of the two folders - I was just hoping that maybe I could do it with one to keep it a bit more simple.